# How to embedded power BI mobile view in IOC

Tags: ionic-framework, powerbi-embedded

please help me how to embedded power BI mobile view with Ionic V6 , I have found the solution but it doesn't work (please refer to this link:https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/power-bi-embedded-in-ionic/75811)

Thank you for your help

Best Regard

firstch

Answer (score 0):

You can set the LayoutType in setttings tp MobilePotratit when passing the embedConfig for embedding the report.

```
let embedConfig = {
    ...
    settings: {
        layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait
    }
};
```

Please find the references below and also the kindly check the limitations with the report mobile view layout

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/mobile